# How to build native Python 2.5 extensions on Windows without Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2003, python-2.5

If you are unlucky and you are forced to use the ancient Python 2.5 on Windows you may encounter another issue: native extensions have to be build with Visual Studio 2003, something you'll not be able to find anymore.

Is there any workaround for this, that does not require VS2003?

BTW, The OS is Windows 7 and please to not tell me that this is an unsupported scenario, I KNOW.

Comment: You don't need a full Visual Studio installation--the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279) contains the command-line compiler(s). And you *should* be able to use the latest compiler with older code... but of course since I haven't tried to build Cpython on Windoze for a while, I couldn't say what kind of options you'll need to use...

Comment: Your statement that you cannot find VS2003 is incorrect. It is extremely easy to find and buy (e.g. on ebay). Much cheaper than spending hours on a solution circumventing VS2003, not knowing what kind of incompatibility problems that might cause.